# Valor passado nas chaves da tag pattern para o nome da classe

Tags: java, log, logback

Estou estudando sobre o Logback para implementar no sistema da minha empresa, e na *tag* `pattern` tenho o seguinte:

```
[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %level [%thread] %class{0} %method %line - %message%n
```

Notei que ao mudar o valor dentro das chaves de `%class` é exibido variações sobre a classe. Gostaria de entender melhor sobre essas variações, e se existe uma tabela a respeito. Pesquisei na documentação do Logback, mas não encontrei nada.
Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Estes são alguns exemplos das saídas que notei:

```
br.com.sosimple.App
App
b.c.s.App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#class), o número que vai entre os colchetes é o tamanho (*length*) que o nome da classe vai ter, mas há alguns detalhes quanto ao seu valor e o resultado final.

Quando o valor é omitido (ou seja, você coloca apenas `%class`), o nome completo da classe (incluindo os nomes dos pacotes) é impresso, e quando o valor é zero (`%class{0}`), apenas o nome da classe (sem os pacotes) é impresso.

Por exemplo, se a classe for `log.test.TestLogback` (nome `TestLogback`, no pacote `log.test`), `%class` imprime `log.test.TestLogback`, e `%class{0}` imprime apenas `TestLogback`.

Já para os outros valores, caso o nome completo da classe seja maior do que o indicado, alguns nomes de pacotes podem ser abreviados. Mas existe um "limite" para abreviação, no qual cada nome de pacote é reduzido para apenas uma letra.

No caso, `log.test.TestLogback` tem 20 caracteres, então dependendo do valor usado, o resultado pode ser:

```
| Tamanho      | Resultado            |
|--------------|----------------------|
| 20 ou mais   | log.test.TestLogback |
| 18 ou 19     | l.test.TestLogback   |
| entre 1 e 17 | l.t.TestLogback      |
```

Um detalhe importante é que o nome da classe não é abreviado, somente os nomes dos pacotes, conforme a necessidade. Tem mais exemplos na [documentação](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#logger).

Claro que os valores acima e os respectivos resultados são para este nome de classe específico. Se eu mudar o nome da classe para `TesteLogback` (adicionei mais um `e` antes do `L`), agora o nome completo da classe possui 21 caracteres. Isso quer dizer que `%class{20}` vai resultar em uma abreviação e o resultado será `l.test.TesteLogback`. Para ter o nome completo, eu teria que usar `%class{21}` (ou qualquer valor maior que 21).

Ou seja, um mesmo valor pode ou não abreviar os pacotes, e vai depender dos nomes das classes e dos pacotes que sua aplicação possui.

Se quiser saber mais a fundo como funciona o algoritmo, pode olhar também no [código fonte](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/pattern/TargetLengthBasedClassNameAbbreviator.java) (e [no seu respectivo *unit test*](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/test/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/pattern/TargetLengthBasedClassNameAbbreviatorTest.java)).

---

Por fim, para valores negativos, o nome completo da classe é impresso, sem abreviações (testei com a versão 1.2.3 do Logback, não sei se outras versões tratam valores negativos de forma diferente).

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo, eu havia testado com diversos valores, mas não cheguei a esta conclusão, e por algum motivo à época, eu não cheguei a ler a documentação. Obrigado